# Simultaneous upload of same file to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I may have two users who are independently using an application to upload a set of files to Azure Storage [Blobs]. There is a possibility that two sets of files being uploaded have one or more common files. Which means that the same file may simultaneously be uploaded from each instance of the application.

- Does the first upload to complete succeed, causing the other upload to fail when it completes, because a file with the same name is already present?
- Or does the first upload that starts succeed, causing the other upload to fail immediately upon detection of another stream being written to the exact same location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to both of your questions is No. Default behavior of Azure Storage is to overwrite a blob if a blob by the same name exists. So in your scenario, blob uploaded by the first user will be overwritten by the blob uploaded by the second user.

However blob upload operation supports [`Conditional Request Headers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-conditional-headers-for-blob-service-operations) and you can ask Azure Storage to fail the second upload operation by including `If-None-Match` request header with value as `*` in your upload request. Then the upload request will only succeed if the blob does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, that will help me handle that scenario